# How to find out what's the first child tag name?

Tags: jquery

I need to find what the first child of an element is.

#### For example:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <img class="child" />
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

In this example the FIRST child is a `div`.

#### Another example:

```
<div class="parent">
    <img class="child" />
    <img class="child" />
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

In this example the first child is a `img`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yet another one:

```
var tag = $('.parent').children().get(0).nodeName;
```

Or if you already have any other reference to the parent element, you can simply access its `children` property (assuming it is a DOM node, not a jQuery object):

```
var tag = parent.children[0].nodeName;
```

**Reference:** [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/), [`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.children), [`Node.nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeName)

Answer (score 6):

This would be one way

```
$('div.parent').children(':first');
```

If you want to know what type of element it is

```
$('div.parent').children(':first')[0].nodeName;
```

The `[0]` will get the first underlying DOM element in the wrapped set.

Comment: I don't want to select it, I need to know what it is. So if I wanted to I could use `alert()` and get `div` or `img`

Comment: ok, but in order to know what it is, you'll need to reference the element in the DOM first. Then you can ascertain what type of element it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.parent *:first-child')
```